# Nested loop only loops once

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a mask for a game board. `mask` is always the same dimension as `revealed`. If mask is False, display '_' in revealed instead current state.

```
mask = [[False, True, False, False],[False, False, False, False]]
revealed = [['.', '3', '1', ' '],['.', '.', '1', ' ']]

def hide(revealed):
    for i, outer in enumerate(mask):
        for j, inner in enumerate(outer): 
            if inner == False: 
                revealed[i][j] = '_'
                return revealed

print(hide(revealed))
```

Expected:

```
[['_', '3', '1', '_'], ['_', '_', '1', '_']]
```

Got:

```
[['_', '3', '1', ' '], ['.', '.', '1', ' ']]
```

Comment: ```return``` marks the end of the function. Move ```return``` outside the loop

Comment: Check `zip()` function. This does almost what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Your *description* of what you want and what you *expect* do not jibe (agree with each other).

Comment: Why do you expect two `'1'` to be displayed, where the mask says `False`?

Answer (score 2):

The `return` keyword is used to mark the end of the function. Since `return` was inside the loop, it only iterated once before it exited the function.

```
mask = [[False, True, False, False],[False, False, False, False]]
revealed = [['.', '3', '1', ' '],['.', '.', '1', ' ']]

def hide(revealed):
    for i, outer in enumerate(mask):
        for j, inner in enumerate(outer): 
            if inner == False: 
                revealed[i][j] = '_'
    return revealed

print(hide(revealed))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a compact solution if you are ok with numpy:

```
import numpy as np

mask = [[False, True, False, False],[False, False, False, False]]
revealed = [['.', '3', '1', ' '],['.', '.', '1', ' ']]

nmask = np.array(mask)
nrevealed = np.array(revealed)

hidden = np.full_like(nrevealed, '_')
hidden[nmask] = nrevealed[nmask]

# hidden is now:
#  array([['_', '3', '_', '_'],
#         ['_', '_', '_', '_']], dtype='<U1')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if inner == False: 
    revealed[i][j] = '_'
    return revealed
```

returns the revealed variable after the first time its evaluated to true so not all the items in array is checked. Move your return statement out side of both loops so it can iterate inside all of the items in array.